# C++ substring - a pointer to a range of a string (loading a big file)

Tags: c++, string, pointers, ram

I have a file like this:

- ACCCTCGGCTACTACGACTAC
- GCTAGTCAGACTGAGCATGTCAGTC
- TAGCTAGCTGACTGACTACATCGAC
- GCTAGATGCTAGCGTATAGTCTGCTGAGTCTGAGT
- GTCAGTCATGTGACTGACGTATGCTATTA

Above file is kinda big, it has 9000 lines which are 100-200 chars long.

I need to insert substrings of these lines in a range of 5 to the map (whole file has to be in the same map).

First line is: ACCCTCGGCTACTACGACTAC so I need to load to the map:

- **ACCCT**CGGCTACTACGACTAC next
- A**CCCTC**GGCTACTACGACTAC next
- AC**CCTCG**GCTACTACGACTAC next
- ...
- ACCCTCGGCTACTACG**ACTAC**

After this we load second line, third, till the eof.

SO. my first idea was:

```
map<string, set<string>> sequences;
int SEQLEN = 74; // cause we load 74 long substrings

while (getline(in, name) && getline(in, chain)) {
    for (int i = 0; i + SEQLEN < chain.size(); i++) {
        string subchain = chain.substr(i, SEQLEN);
        sequences[subchain].insert(name);
    }
}
```

but after this we have a map, which consumes 4.5 gb of RAM, which is unacceptable, cause PC on which it should work has only 2 GB's :C

I heard about some kind of 'pointers to string's chars'. If something like this exists, I could just load all of the lines and save pointers to 'start char' and 'end char' for these substrings and then just load them by providing this 'range'.

What do you think, is there something like 'pointers to string's certain char'?

If someone has ANY idea, I would be grateful :)

Comment: If you have a bleeding edge compiler, [`std::experimental::string_view`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/basic_string_view), else [Boost `string_ref`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/utility/doc/html/string_ref.html).

Comment: Create a map that stores all the lines and a second map that stores just the `(start, end)` indices for strings in the first map.

Comment: @kfx The question is basically how to do just that.

Comment: Do your strings actually encode nucleobases, or do they look like ones by coincidence?

Comment: Yeah, it is a Escheria Coli genom

Comment: I'm not getting the purpose of this. Are you trying to count how many times each substring occurs? Or are you just trying to see which substrings occur?

Comment: Every nucleobase has it's name above like this http://pastebin.com/JRThQMVL.
I need to make 74 chars long substrings from all lines (these ACTG lines)
and push them as keys, and as a value, assign it's name above. 
If we have a name JACOB
and a chain ACTGTCAG (and subsequence must be 5)
we push: map[JACOB].insert(ACTGT)
map[JACOB].insert(CTGTC)
till the end. Map values are Sets of strings.

Next, I have to print these groups (only lists of names) and their sizes to the second file.

The whole app is just to group names of the substring which occur.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your strings encode nucleobases, and you are concerned about saving memory, the best approach is to get rid of strings completely.

With four nucleobase characters in your alphabet, there are only 4<sup>5</sup> or 1024 possible sub-strings of length 5. You can encode each one of them as a `short` integer number by doing a lookup, and then decode it for output by doing a reverse lookup.

This approach will save you a lot of memory: an array of 1024 strings and an `std::map<std::string,short>` needed for lookups will take about 50K of memory. Storing each individual 5-character substring will cost you two bytes, instead of 14 on a 32-bit system or 22 on a 64-bit system. Your entire file could be stored in under one megabyte of memory.

Comment: very pragmatic and practical answer

Comment: Yeah, this is perfect, but my substrings are 74 long, not 5 :v My fault, but +1 for pointing this :)

Comment: @Kuba You could still save 4x memory by compressing your 74-character strings to 19 bytes. Rather than storing a single character per byte, store four two-bit chunks, and write a pair of functions for converting to and from this compressed format.